# how to put my arguments into a Bash alias command?

Tags: bash, alias, arguments

i usually have the following simple alias in my bashrc:

`alias g="grep --color=always --exclude-dir=\*.svn\*"`

but now i have to work on systems that only have GNU grep 2.5, hence no `--exclude-dir` argument.

now i need something like this to work:

`alias g="grep --color=always $1 $2 | grep -v .svn"`

but of course, the arguments get appended to the end of the alias. $1 and $2 are parsed when the alias is created not when it's called, even with strong quotes.

Can i solve that without resorting to extra scripts or functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't.  As the bash manual states:

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in `csh'.  If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (*note Shell Functions::).

Functions are the right thing for this, and can be as easy to write as an alias. In this case, it could be

```
function g () { grep --color=always "$1" "$2" | grep -v .svn ; }
```

Comment: +1 Safer to quote the positional params.

Comment: Very true. Edited to correct that.